# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.15:test (default-test) on project

Tags: maven, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

POM.XML has:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
       <suiteXmlFile>src\test\resources\all_testing.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
    </configuration> 
</plugin>
```

when I include below tags in POM.xml I'm getting the error:

```
"Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.15:test (default-test) on project"
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<suiteXmlFiles>
       <suiteXmlFile>src\test\resources\all_testing.xml</suiteXmlFile>
</suiteXmlFiles>
```

Try to replace back slashes ('\') with slashes ('/') inside the 'suiteXmlFile' tags.